# How to call top level from lapply loop (skip/pass)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, lapply

I want to create a lapply loop that if attends a certain requirement, it will stop...
as an example:

```
score <- 0
lapply(1:100, function(z){

    score <<- score + 1

    if(score >=10){
        break
    }
})
```

However, there is no stop argument as **break/pass** in a lapply loop.

I know this example sounds stupid. However, the original code has too many dependencies to be easily understood...
My original loop removes an item from a vector an object every time, however, if there is nothing else to be removed from it can stop.
I've gain at least 0.10 seconds with this in a normal loop short sized function

#### with normal "for loop" with skip argument

```
> time <- system.time({cyclopeptide_score(sequence, spectrum)})
> time
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
     6.58      0.00      6.58
```

#### with laplly with no skip argument

```
> time <- system.time({cyclopeptide_score2(sequence, spectrum)})
> time
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
     6.72      0.00      6.72
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, here is an option (assuming you have some control of the code where the `lapply` happens, and of the function being applied):

```
withRestarts(
  lapply(
    1:10, 
    function(x) {
      cat(x)
      if(x > 5) invokeRestart("stopLoop")
  } ),
  stopLoop=function() message("Loop Stopped")
)
```

Produces:

```
123456
Loop Stopped
```

Basically, `withRestarts`/`invokeRestart` acts a little bit like a GOTO statement, which allows you to break out of the loop.

All this said, I wouldn't base any big code refactorings efforts on a 0.1 second improvement on 6.7 seconds run time.

Also, if you can do the above, you can probably just as easily turn your code into a `for` loop, which seems more appropriate given your desire to a) break out of the loop, b) use the `<<-` operator to cause side effects.

Comment: Thanks BrodieG worked like a charm, btw, why does <<- causes side effects?

Comment: @RodrigoBertollodeAlexandre, the term "side effects" in programming refers to functions affecting the programming environment other than through their return value.  `<<-` sets the value of a variable outside of the functions scope, so it is considered a side effect.  Side effects are can be problematic because it means you have to think beyond just the input and output values of a function when programming, which limits the usefulness of functions as modular components.