# In an apply function, how can I get partial results if there is an error?

Tags: r

I am doing some web scraping in R and storing the results in a data frame. If an error trips up the function, I would like to be able to see the results retrieved up to that point. An example of an error I have seen is `Error in data.frame... arguments imply differing number of rows`.

Here is a reproducible example. When the error appears on the second iteration, I'd like to able to see the results from the first. Is this a matter of error handling? Do I need to do it in a `for` loop instead?

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
    cat("Now processing :", x, "\n")
    v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
    df <- data.frame(v1, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    cat("Data frame completed", "\n")
    return(df)
}

v2 <- c(1:4)
v3 <- c(5:9)
list1 <- list(v2, v3)

result <- lapply(list1, myfunc)
```

Comment: Possibly `result <- lapply(list1, function(x) {
  try(myfunc(x), silent=TRUE)
})`

Comment: @nrussell that will keep going after an error - a different approach is needed if the poster wants to return only up to the first error... Kevin M, can you clarify?

Comment: Can I suggest `myfunc=function(x){if(x==7){stop("ouch")};return(paste0("X=",x))}` as a simpler example? Test case is `sapply(1:10, myfunc)`, and `sapply(1:10, function(x){try(myfunc(x))})`

Comment: or put a tryCatch in your function, `df <- tryCatch(data.frame(v1, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), error = function(e) e)`, or you can change `e` to `NULL` or whatev

Comment: One "problem" is that the `*apply` functions do not have stateful memory, meaning they do not know where in the original vector/array they are currently executing, nor is their access to previous results. You may be able to side-step it sloppily with something like `err <- FALSE; myfunc <- function(x) { if (! err) tryCatch(..., error={ err <<- TRUE; }); }`. Reaching out of scope like this is discouraged but may work, though your return vector will have `NULL`s in every place *after* the error.

Comment: There's an example if short-circuit quitting an `lapply` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873844/how-to-call-top-level-from-lapply-loop-skip-pass but it can't return anything. Returning something of length `<N` from an `lapply` over something of length `N` just smells bad to me. +1 for for loop, or while loop, or repeat loop...

Comment: For this purpose, it's fine if the function keeps running. I can go back and find the errors. The main point of asking the question is I didn't want to see the work (even incomplete) of the web scraping go to waste. I could at least use it for debugging. The first suggestion from @nrussell worked for my purposes.

Comment: For this particular application, I'm thinking that it's better to not do the data frame conversion during the web scraping. I'm thinking I can just keep the data elements in a list so that the scraping continues to run and pulls all of the data the first time around. However, there's still the issue of the mismatched lengths, addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504327/using-xml-to-associate-the-values-of-children-and-parent-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I like the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873844/how-to-call-top-level-from-lapply-loop-skip-pass) that @Spacedman provided for its lack of side-effects, the comment over returning a different length can also be problematic.

I propose this as a second-rate alternative to the use of `withRestarts` that maintains the length of the list. (You could always sandwich the `withRestarts` implementation to ensure the list is padded at the end, thereby avoiding both side-effects and short-sheeting the returned list.)

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
    if (! err) {
        message("Now processing :", x)
        v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
        tryCatch({
            dfm <- data.frame(v1, x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            message("Data frame completed")
            return(dfm)
        }, error = function(e) {
            message("Problems processing, gracefully exiting")
            err <<- TRUE
            NULL
        })
    }
}

v2 <- c(1:4)
v3 <- c(5:9)
list1 <- list(v2, v3)

err <- FALSE
result <- lapply(list1, myfunc)
## Now processing :1234
## Data frame completed
## Now processing :56789
## Problems processing, gracefully exiting

result
## [[1]]
##   v1 x
## 1  A 1
## 2  B 2
## 3  C 3
## 4  D 4
## [[2]]
## NULL
```

You need to reset `err <- FALSE` every time you encounter an error (and want to re-run the loop).

I'm not particularly fond of reaching out of the scope of the `lapply` call, but I know of no other way to accomplish this.